# First steps to designing user interface for database

Tags: sql, database, database-connection

I'm in the process of starting a personal project to assist my day-job as a teacher. I am wanting to create a tool which can store and analyse exam data.

What would be the best option for creating the user interface with the database? Ideally, each other teacher would be able to log in, enter test scores and potentially access some pre-made reports on the data. When entering data they could be entering 30+ students' data, with 40+ data points per student for each exam.

I am planning on using SQL as I have a little experience in that.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: That's a very broad question (and I can see this getting flagged because of this).  Basically you have a number of options, some of which will probably not be a good fit.  I would start with website/ web service, windows application, tool that comes with database (e.g. Access forms or SSMS), command line, sucking in text files, Excel, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've had a bad habit of asking bad questions recently! Not intentional, probably due to being more adventurous with my projects.
A couple of your suggestions (excel file in particular) sound very useful, thanks.

Comment: If you are going to go down the Excel route then you could consider a number of options here also.  You could actually design a full user interface in Excel using VSTO (if you have .NET), or something a little clunkier using VBA, or even more basic with simple Excel workbooks being dropped into the database (using SSIS or manually loading these) and reports working the same but in reverse?  Excel makes a really good interface in many ways, as it's easy to manage table data, and importing/ exporting data is relatively painless.